# Unable to set Admob Banner in Bottom

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to set my admob banner on bottom of the screen but it's not showing. I have tried all possible way to set it as bottom but I am unable to set it...its going down side of expandable list view.

My XML is like below...let me know if someone can help me to sort out issue.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#e7e7e7"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">



    <include
        layout="@layout/top_points_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/five">

    </View>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">



        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/laytop_imgwidthheight"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/laytop_imgwidthheight"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:src="@drawable/app_icon"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:padding="@dimen/five"
            android:text="Country of Purchase"
            android:textColor="@color/Gray"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_country_selection"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/list_item_background"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="6dp">

            <com.commonutility.RoundImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_country_logo"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/country_default_logo"
                android:visibility="visible" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_country_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView_country_logo"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="Select Your Country"
                android:textColor="@color/Blue"
                android:textSize="19sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dropdown" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/five"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/five"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/five"
            android:text="Country"
            android:textColor="#fe4080"
            android:textSize="@dimen/rewards_countrytextsize"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtcountry"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/five"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/five"
            android:text="USA"
            android:textColor="@color/material_color_primary_dark"
            android:textSize="@dimen/rewards_countrytextsize"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/list_item_background"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:divider="@color/md_white_1000"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:groupIndicator="@null"
        android:scrollbars="none" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Let me know what is wrong in this.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

works only in RelativeLayout, but it's inside a LinearLayout.

You could change the root layout to RelativeLayout and wrap everything but your AdView inside another LinearLayout (or better handle the behaviour of the other views as expected inside a RelativeLayout to avoid deep layouts).

Comment: I am unable to use RelativeLayout  because of some view issue... There no any way to set bottom in LinearLayout ?

Comment: Hi ! I have solve puzzle by put layout_weight="1" in my expandable list view..Thanks for the Answer

Comment: With orientation="vertical", all views will be aligned vertical. So the last View you add to the LinearLayout will be at the bottom, but only at the bottom of the view, not of the screen.